# A simple Code about CUDA Warps

Tags: cuda

I have read in the Cuda Documentaion that , inside each block threads are executed in a batch of 32 called warps, each thread points at same instruction but multiple data can be accessed, my quest was to test out the authenticity of the statement.

Now what i did is i launched a kernel with 256 threads and a single block, so 8 batches 
of warps must be executed.

I shall create a shared variable of size 32, assign it to

```
sharedVariable [ threadIdx.x % 32 ] = threadIdx.x /32;
```

and then assign that variable to global variable of 256 byte length:

```
outputPointer[ threadIdx.x  ] = sharedVariable [ threadIdx.x % 32 ];
```

Ideally, according to the assumption i should get output as

0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,till 32
1,1,1,1,1,1till 32..
2,2,2,2,2,till 32

but i am getting output as just 4,4,4,4,4

Cuda Code:

```
__global__ void addKernel(int *inputPointer, int *outputPointer)
{
    __shared__ int sharedVariable[ 32 ];

    sharedVariable [ threadIdx.x % 32 ] = 0 ;
    sharedVariable [ threadIdx.x % 32 ] = threadIdx.x /32;


    outputPointer[ threadIdx.x  ] = sharedVariable [ threadIdx.x % 32 ];
}

int main () { 
......
 addKernel<<<1, 256>>>(device_inputPointer, device_outputPointer);
......
/**Print output here */
//I am getting 4 ,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4 as output
}
```

Complete Code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <conio.h>
#define SIZE  256 * sizeof(int)


__global__ void addKernel(int *inputPointer, int *outputPointer)
{
    __shared__ int sharedVariable[ 32 ];


    sharedVariable [ threadIdx.x % 32 ] = 0;

    sharedVariable [ threadIdx.x % 32 ] = threadIdx.x /32;


    outputPointer[ threadIdx.x  ] = sharedVariable [ threadIdx.x % 32 ];
}



int main()
{





    // Copy input vectors from host memory to GPU buffers.
    int *inputPointer = (int * ) malloc (SIZE);
    int *outputPointer= (int * ) malloc (SIZE);


    int *device_inputPointer;
    int *device_outputPointer;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&device_inputPointer, SIZE);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&device_outputPointer, SIZE);

    memset (inputPointer  , 0  ,  SIZE);
    cudaMemcpy(device_inputPointer , inputPointer,  SIZE , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Launch a kernel on the GPU with one thread for each element.
    addKernel<<<1, 256>>>(device_inputPointer, device_outputPointer);

    cudaMemcpy(outputPointer, device_outputPointer, SIZE , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // cudaDeviceReset must be called before exiting in order for profiling and
    // tracing tools such as Nsight and Visual Profiler to show complete traces.

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 256  ; i ++ ) {
        printf ( " %d  " , outputPointer[i] );
    }

    cudaDeviceReset();



    getch();
    return 0;
}

#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <conio.h>
#define SIZE  256 * sizeof(int)


__global__ void addKernel(int *inputPointer, int *outputPointer)
{
    __shared__ int sharedVariable[ 32 ];


    sharedVariable [ threadIdx.x % 32 ] = 0;

    sharedVariable [ threadIdx.x % 32 ] = threadIdx.x /32;


    outputPointer[ threadIdx.x  ] = sharedVariable [ threadIdx.x % 32 ];
}



int main()
{





    // Copy input vectors from host memory to GPU buffers.
    int *inputPointer = (int * ) malloc (SIZE);
    int *outputPointer= (int * ) malloc (SIZE);


    int *device_inputPointer;
    int *device_outputPointer;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&device_inputPointer, SIZE);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&device_outputPointer, SIZE);

    memset (inputPointer  , 0  ,  SIZE);
    cudaMemcpy(device_inputPointer , inputPointer,  SIZE , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Launch a kernel on the GPU with one thread for each element.
    addKernel<<<1, 256>>>(device_inputPointer, device_outputPointer);

    cudaMemcpy(outputPointer, device_outputPointer, SIZE , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // cudaDeviceReset must be called before exiting in order for profiling and
    // tracing tools such as Nsight and Visual Profiler to show complete traces.

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 256  ; i ++ ) {
        printf ( " %d  " , outputPointer[i] );
    }

    cudaDeviceReset();



    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I tested it on different hardware 
on K20 (Tesla Architecture, it is working fine )

Comment: I couldn't think of a way to accomplish what you are trying to do, so I reframed the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21558351/442006

Answer (score 2):

The code has undefined behavior in the following lines:

```
 sharedVariable [ threadIdx.x % 32 ] = 0;
 sharedVariable [ threadIdx.x % 32 ] = threadIdx.x /32;
```

Multiple threads can have same value of `threadIdx.x % 32` and these threads would try to write to the same shared memory location simultaneously. This will cause a race condition between these threads.

For example, consider the threads with `threadIdx.x` 0, 32, 64, 96...etc. All of these threads will try to access the index `0` of the `sharedVariable` thus causing undefined behavior. Same is the case with all threads which are at an offset of `32` from each other (In current example only).

Comment: But at a time only one warp shall be scheduled in the hardware right ? and hence there shall be no overwriting.

Comment: It doesn't matter when the warp is scheduled. When looking at the bigger picture, all threads just execute independent of each other. As @hubs has pointed out, there will be a race condition among the threads, and the memory will have the value which is assigned by the last thread. On my machine, I get `5` in the output.

Comment: For `threadIdx.x` = 0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192 and 224 `threadIdx.x % 32` is every time `0`! These are the first thread of each warp. Divided by 32 the result written to `sharedVariable [0]` can be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 or 7.

Comment: @hubs... That is correct, but we don't know which warp would be the last one to access the memory.

Comment: @sgar91 yes of course, therefore I wrote it can be 0,1,2.. Sorry if it wasn't fully clear what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not fully clear to you how cuda code is executed in parallel.
The line `sharedVariable [ threadIdx.x % 32 ] = 0 ;` is complete useless because in the next line you overwrite it with `threadIdx.x /32`.

Also your assumption of the warp count is wrong. Your threadblock consists of 256 threads. So there are 8 warps (256/32).

You cannot expect any results from your code, because there is no defined behaivour! The results of `threadIdx.x /32` wil be in range from 0 to 7, depending on `threadIdx.x` that is in range 0..255.
Because there are 8 warps of each 32 threads, there will be 8 writes to `sharedVariable [ threadIdx.x % 32 ]` and you have no control, which warp will be executed first and last.

In your case warp 4 was executed at last and therefore your results are only 4's.

To achieve the results that you expect from your kernel, it canbe changed to:

```
__global__ void addKernel(int *outputPointer)
{
    outputPointer[ threadIdx.x  ] = threadIdx.x /32;
}
```

I see no opportunity for the use of shared memory like you want to.

Comment: the order in which the warp will get executed is not a problem in the above code i think, as long as one warp is executed at a time the above code must work right ?

Comment: Of course, as @sgar91 said, too, there is a reace condition between the threads of different warps. If I launch the code on my system I get only 6's.